# Terraform loop data source and locals in a single resource

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to create Azure role assignments using the below variable

```
variable "role_assignments" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "Contributor" = ["prod-azure-contrib-sbox"],
    "Owner"       = ["gcp-org-cloud-delivery"]
  }
}
```

flatten the variable

```
locals {
  groupsbyrole = flatten([
    for roleName, groupList in var.role_assignments : [
      for groupName in groupList : {
        role_name  = roleName
        group_name = groupName
      }
    ]
  ])
  }
```

The code for creating the role assignments are below

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
    for_each = {
    for group in local.groupsbyrole : "${group.role_name}.${group.group_name}}" => group
    
  }
    scope                            = azurerm_resource_group.az-rg.id
    role_definition_name             = each.value.role_name
    principal_id =  each.value.group_name
    skip_service_principal_aad_check = var.skip_service_principal_aad_check
}
```

Unfortunately, the principal_id needs to be the object id and not the name which in this case ends up as prod-azure-contrib-sbox or gcp-org-cloud-delivery. Now entry data sources to get the object_id

```
data "azuread_group" "group" {
 display_name =  either prod-azure-contrib-sbox or gcp-org-cloud-delivery
}
```

Somehow I need to assign the principal_id in the above resource block with the corresponding azuread_group.group.object_id.

Been trying various ways. One way is to get the data source values into a list to use it in azurerm_role_assignment but it needs two loops and it Terraform doesnt support that. Tried to get the data source inside the resource block and that's not allowed either.

Any other ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: Getting error .  Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidPrincipalId" Message="The Principal ID 'gcp-org-cloud-delivery' is not valid. Principal ID must be a GUID."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `for_each` in your data source:

```
data "azuread_group" "group" {
    for_each = {
         for group in local.groupsbyrole : 
           "${group.role_name}.${group.group_name}" => group
    }

    display_name =   each.value.group_name
}
```

then

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
    for_each = {
         for group in local.groupsbyrole : 
          "${group.role_name}.${group.group_name}" => group    
    }
    scope                            = azurerm_resource_group.az-rg.id
    role_definition_name             = each.value.role_name
    principal_id                     = data.azuread_group.group[each.key].object_id
    skip_service_principal_aad_check = var.skip_service_principal_aad_check
}
```

Comment: that did the trick. Thank you. Wasnt able to figure out the data.azuread_group.group[each.key] part.